# もちゃもちゃっと meaning

Tags: meaning, onomatopoeia

> 「ちっちゃくてかわいいってことだよ」
> 「抱き上げて、もちゃもちゃっとしたくなっちゃう系の」

Can't define words in this phrase もちゃもちゃっと. That is some sort of slang or contraction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

もちゃもちゃ is not common at all, and I don't think I have seen it before. But there is a word [もふもふ](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%83%A2%E3%83%95%E3%83%A2%E3%83%95), which is a super popular mimetic word today. ちゃ in a mimetic word is commonly associated with a sense of messiness (see [わちゃわちゃ](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%8F%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%8F%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83), [ごちゃごちゃ](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%94%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%81%94%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83), [ぐちゃぐちゃ](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%90%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%81%90%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83)). So people can intuit もちゃもちゃっとする (or もちゃもちゃする) is a little bit more aggressive version of もふもふする (or [もふる](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%83%A2%E3%83%95%E3%82%8B) for short).

People often [improvise unique onomatopoeic/mimetic words](http://leodraco.blog120.fc2.com/blog-entry-377.html), so you may have to understand them through your imagination.